# TYPO3 8.7 can not override Fluid Styled Content templates

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-8.x, fluid-styled-content

I've tried to override the Fluid Styled Content elements but it doesn't work at all in latest TYPO3 version 8.7.0.

I've got a template extension (key: biv_main) in which I add my overriding template pathes:

```
lib {
fluidContent {
        templateRootPaths {
            30 = EXT:biv_main/Resources/Private/Content/fluid_styled_content/Templates/
        }
        partialRootPaths {
            30 = EXT:biv_main/Resources/Private/Content/fluid_styled_content/Partials/
        }
        layoutRootPaths {
            30 = EXT:biv_main/Resources/Private/Content/fluid_styled_content/Layouts/
        }
    }
}
```

The TypoScript in the Backend via TS Object Browser looks correct to me:
[Screenshot TypoScript object browser - lib.fluidcontent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XuXh.png)

I have copied the whole template, partial and layout folder with every file in it from sysext fluid_styled_content, so that every content element should be overridden.

This is my folder structure in the template extension:

```
biv_main
-- Resources
  -- Private
    -- Content
      -- fluid_styled_content 
        -- Layouts
        -- Partials 
        -- Templates
```

In the folders are exactly the same files as in sys-ext fluid_styled_content/Resources/Private/

The static typoscript template for Fluid Content Elements are loaded before the template extension biv_main.

Do you have any ideas or a clue what's missing and why it's not working?

Comment: For me it works fine. I direclty used the TS Constants styles.templates.templateRootPath, styles.templates.partialRootPath, 
styles.templates.layoutRootPath.
The only thing that I noticed is the "fluid_styled_content" with lowercase intial letter.

Comment: Please try to change the first `F` in `fluid_styled_content` to upper case.

Comment: Where do you use the `lib.fluidContent`? You TS will not override `tt_content.*` and you need to define the override before any copy usage of the `lib.fluidContent`.

Comment: See `typo3_src-8.7.4\typo3\sysext\fluid_styled_content\Configuration\TypoScript\Helper\ContentElement.txt` fallback.. `lib.fluidContent < lib.contentElement`. And it still doesn't work?

Answer (score 22):

The TypoScript lib has changed see 
[Overriding the FLUID templates](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/fluid_styled_content/8.7/Configuration/OverridingFluidTemplates/)

So you need to override `lib.contentElement` instead of `lib.fluidContent`

Comment: Saved my life. Thanks!

Comment: Please consider marking this question as solved if it helped you. Thanks!

Comment: @KlausFragenbert mark this answer, will help other people.